# Generating random numbers inside an array

Tags: java, arrays, random, average, prefix

I have a some pseudo code which I made into java code. It is the calculation of prefix averages:

```
Algorithm 4.1. PrefixAverages1(X)
Input: X, a 1-D numerical array of size n
1) Let A = an empty 1-D numerical array of size n
2) For i = 0 to n-1
3)    Let s = X[0]
4)    For j = 1 to i
5)       Let s = s + X[j]
6)    End For
7)   Let A[i] = s /(i+1)
8) End For
Output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i]
        is the average of elements X[0],X[1], … ,X[i]
```

And here is the java code that I wrote:

```
public class Prefix1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        algo1();
        }
private static void algo1(){
        int X[] = new int[10];
        int randomNumber;
        int o = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<o; i++) {
            randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
            X[i] = randomNumber;
        }
        int n = X.length;
        int A[] = new int [n];


        for (int i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
        {
            int s = X[0];
            for (int j=1; j<i; ++j)
            {
                s = s + X[j];
            }

            A[i] = s / (i+1);
        }

    }
```

The problem I have is that I'm unsure as to how generate random numbers into this array and then running this array through the algortihm. I'm sure that my java code is correct, based on the pseudo code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Always define "not working".

Comment: Do you know that first for loop is running for one time only?

Comment: for starter, because your o=1, you are not populating whole array, but  you putting only one element

Comment: IT doesn't generate random numbers, just random charcters

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your for loop. It effectively says `i < 1`. Use the length of the array:

```
    for (int i=0; i<X.length; i++) {
        randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
        X[i] = randomNumber;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but when I print out A or X, I get the output: [I@45bab50a     @KaiSternad

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the array ? You can't directly print it out.

Comment: I tried it and it is now printing out the numbers in the array, but I just realised that I want to print is the average of the numbers in the array. @Kai

Comment: Then iterate over the array, add all numbers and finally divide by the lenth of the array, something like this: double avg = 0; for (int i : X){ avg+=i }; avg = avg / X.length

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your issue:

```
 int o = 1;
 for (int i=0; i<o; i++) {
```

you have only populated for `i=0` and stopped when `i=1`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to fill the whole array with random numbers. As you set `o=1`, you just set the first element of the array to a random number.

```
private static void algo1(){
    int X[] = new int[10];
    int randomNumber;
    for (int i=0; i<X.length; i++) {
        X[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your `For` Loop `o = 1` so only on time the loop will work

```
        int o = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<o; i++) {
            randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
            X[i] = randomNumber;
        }
```

So change `o` as `X.length`;

```
        int o =  X.length;
        for (int i=0; i<o; i++) {
            randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
            X[i] = randomNumber;
        }
```